# Mismatch in number of records loaded shown by Informatica monitor and mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, informatica

I am using Informatica 9.6.1 and I have mongodb version 3.x.
When I run the WF, informatica monitor shows 9345 rows successfully loaded but when I check mongodb collection I see only 9333 records. There is difference of 12 records. This issue happening frequently now. Did you guys faced any issue like this or have any resolution for this issue ?

thanks you so much for help.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the summary from the session log file? It should indicate the numer of applied, affected and rejected rows for each target.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an update strategy before the target? If inserts,  updates and deletes are being routed through same update strategy to the same target and the load type is 'data driven' then the record count in target will be different to the number of records applied. I.e. inserted 100 and updated 10 of same records will be logged as 110 rows applied